# DD4T PreviewPage not working

Tags: dd4t

I have implemented PagePreview in Tridion using DD4T PagePreview tbb. Also follow this blog -http://blog.trivident.com/previewing-pages-with-dd4t/

But i'm always getting below error

*There was an error while generating the preview*

I couldn't figure out what went wrong as everything look fine as per the blog.

Comment: Have you tried running it in the template builder? Sometimes you get more useful feedback there. Put it in debug mode!

Comment: Hi Quirijn,  yes I tried running in template builder and i'm getting 500 error in response. I tried passing Page Xml manually then it's working correctly but not from Tridion end or template builder end